# How to run etcdutl in a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

On Kubernetes, I am trying to restore an `etcd` backup, but running the following command issue a warning:

```shell
kubectl exec -t -n openshift-etcd etcd-crc-qm2dw-master-0 -- sh -c 'ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl     -w fields snapshot status /var/lib/etcd/etcd-snapshot.db'
Deprecated: Use `etcdutl snapshot status` instead.
...
```

Is there an easy way run etcdutl in a pod please? Note that `/var/lib` is mounted using `hostPath` so I could easily mount it in the `etcdutl` pod if I understand how to launch it.